# what does omniauth 1.0.1 do?

Tags: omniauth

I'm currently trying to use omniauth in my rails application. I was just curious, what does the omniauth 1.0.1 gem do now that the provider strategies come in separate gems like omniauth-facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'omniauth 1.0.1' gem is core library. 
'omniauth-facebook' gem is current provider implementation.

[Docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/intridea/omniauth/master/frames)